# jquery.validate: Multiple Remote Rules

Tags: jquery, validation

I plan to validate a single text field with two remote rules. More like this.

```
$('#form').validate({
   rules:{
      remote: 'url1.php',
      remote: 'url2.php'
   },
   messages:{
      remote: 'Error1',
      remote: 'Error2'
   }
});
```

Is this possible? I would want separate error messages for the two remote rules.

Hope to get some help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First I will say that as far as I know you have to nest the validation methods under a certain attribute - you can't just put them on global scope. This would make your code look like this:

```
$('#form').validate({
   rules:{
      attribute1: {
        remote_check_1: true,
        remote_check_2: true
      }
   },
    messages:{
      attribute1:{
        remote_check_1: 'Error1',
        remote_check_2: 'Error2'
      }
    }

});
```

I don't know if you can put the both under the rules object and raise different error messages for them.

What you can do is create two custom validation functions, each with different name. The result would look like:

```
$.validator.addMethod(
    "remote_check_1",
    function(value, element) {
      res = $.ajax({url: 'url1.php', data: { attribute1: value }, dataType: 'json'});
    return res;
    }
 );



$.validator.addMethod(
        "remote_check_2",
        function(value, element) {
          res = $.ajax({url: 'url2.php', data: { attribute1: value }, dataType: 'json'});
        return res;
        }
     );
```

Answer (score 0):

jquery.validation is NOT support multiple remote validation in single field.

But you can merge two remote validation by merge the validation handlers on server side.

Answer (score 0):

> $.validator.addMethod("remote_check_1", function(value, element) { var data; $.ajax({ url: 'url1.php', type: 'post' data: { attribute1: value }, dataType: 'json', async: false, success: function(res) { data = res } }); return data; });

> $.validator.addMethod("remote_check_2", function(value, element) { var data; $.ajax({ url: 'url.php', type: 'post' data: { attribute1: value }, dataType: 'json', async: false, success: function(res) { data = res } }); return data; });

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please, format the code and provide an explanation in order to improve your answer and make it more understandable for the community