# Use more than one remote ajax on jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I want to make validation on Email using jQuery

A regular validation (required) and other verification using Ajax

first function to validate if email exist and other to verify is not in black list (other table)

```
$('#form').validate({
  errorElement: 'span',
  rules:{                
     Email: {
        required: true,
        email: true,
        remote: '/ifexist'
       }
     },
     messages:{
        Email:{
            remote:'email already exist'
          }
        }
   });
```

I try to add other remote like this, but it doesn't work

```
remote: '/ifexist'
remote: '/inblacklist'
```

My php code

```
if(isset($_GET['Email'])){
   $is_valid = Member::inblacklist($email);
   header('Content-Type: application/json');
   echo json_encode($is_valid);
 }else{}
```

Any solution ?

Comment: Why wouldn't you validate both by the same endpoint? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery.validate: Multiple Remote Rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284044/jquery-validate-multiple-remote-rules)

Comment: @RomeoSierra if I make in the same function I can't know what is the message of each one

Comment: @RomeoSierra I learn the post, but I search if there method like this without define jQuery functions

Comment: If you can't do 2 remotes could always check in the submitHandler for the blacklist before submitting

Comment: *I make in the same function I can't know what is the message of each one* -> not entirely true.

Comment: @RomeoSierra sir, I make my php code, is there any solution to add both function and know the message of each one ?

Comment: Yes, sir indeed. From the way I see it, it's just an `if` nested in another `if`.

Comment: @RomeoSierra, but how can I get the error message ?

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13284994/3126973) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284044/jquery-validate-multiple-remote-rules) ***claims that*** the jQuery validation plugin does not support multiple remotes (I haven't seen any credible evidence to prove neither the claim nor otherwise, **yet**). I'd have done something as follows if I was to handle your case.

```
$('#form').validate({
    errorElement: 'span',
    rules:{                
        Email: {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            remote: {
                url:'/ifexist',
                type:'POST', //Or whatever
                data:function(){
                    return $("#email").val(); // The value of the email field
                },
                dataType:"JSON", // So that you can return a JSON object from the backend
                dataFilter:function(responseData){ // Handles the response
                    /* Assume you return a JSON object as follows
                     * {"isValid":false, "reason":"blacklisted"}
                     * or may be
                     * {"isValid":false, "reason":"duplicate"}
                     */
                    alert(responseData.reason); // Or whatever
                    return responseData.isValid; // validation result
                }
            }
        }
    },
    // Rest of the validation logic
```

What happens here is that, you take control the response from the backend's validation routine and handle it as you desire.

The plugin is almost fully customizable. Refer to the [documentation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) for futher details.

**EDIT (after updates to the original question)**

Backend in php may be something as follows.

```
if(isset($_POST['Email'])){
    $email = $_POST['Email'];
    $response = null;
    $isInBlackList = Member::inblacklist($email);
    if($isBlackList){
        // User is in the blacklist
        $response = array("isValid"=>false, "message"=>"This email is blacklisted!"); // Initialize $response
    }
    else{
        $alreadyExists = Member::alreadyExists($email); // You have to implement this.
        if($alreadyExists){
            // Email already exists
            $response = array("isValid"=>false, "message"=>"This email is already in user"); // Initialize $response
        }
        else{
            // We found a valid email
            $response = array("isValid"=>true);
        }
    }
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    echo json_encode($response);
}else{}
```

Notice the usage of php `array()` to encapuslate the response and return that as JSON.

Comment: thanks sir for your reply, your answer is logic, but what I need to change in my php function ?

Comment: @PHPSA why don't you update your question with the php code that you have already written? Then may be we could help.

Comment: Added the required php routine. But remember, this is **my perspective on your scenario**. There are many other ways that you could implement this.

Comment: that's work perfectly with some change, but can I show the error message here ? `messages:{
        Email:{
            remote:'email already exist'
          }
        }`

Comment: Refer to the documentation please.

Comment: Found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44784115/3126973) as well. Couldn't check if that works yet though..

Comment: I'm sorry sir for the inconvenience, but All things works but I have an error in this part `return $("#email").val();` on jQuery, the Email doesn't send to php, for that I always get the response on the first `else`

Comment: That's actually my bad. From the backend you are sending a `POST` request, while the backend is expecting a `GET`. Change the php code to `if(isset($_POST['Email'])){`. I have updated the answer as well. BTW, no offence but, those kinda problems are simple debugging issues. You should be able to find those out by yourself.

Comment: No sir, it's not the problem, because I try with `GET`, `POST`, and when I check where's the error I found in here `return $("#email").val();` no data sending to PHP code

Comment: Sir modify you JS code,  ` type:'POST'` become `GET`, and url:'/ifexist' become `url:'/ifexist?Email='+$('#email').val();` and drop `data:function(){
                    return $("#email").val(); // The value of the email field
                },`
I will give you the correct answer